# IllegalStateException Fragment Manager Already In Use

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs, fragmentmanager

I have been implementing Navigation drawer and tabs within some fragments of navigation drawer for a long time now. The issue never came up and it still does not appears in few fragments but it appears in only two of the fragments in navigation drawer.

In navigation drawer each item represents a fragment which are opened by following code

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
currentFragment = new SomeFragment();
home_container_drawer_layout.closeDrawers();
fragmentTransaction = setFTAnimation(fragmentTransaction);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.framelayout_activity_home, currentFragment).commitNow();
```

As soon as the fragment is loaded I make a service call using ION wrapper that I created and on response I set up tabs dynamically in a ViewPager in that fragment

Following are two functions for setting tab listener and setting viewpager adapter

```
 private void addListeners() {
        pager_account_cash_mail.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tablayout_fragment_account_cash_mail));
        tablayout_fragment_account_cash_mail.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            pager_account_cash_mail.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });
}
   private void setAdapter() {
        mAdapter = new CashMailPagerAdapter(this.getChildFragmentManager(), tabs_fragments_list);
        pager_account_cash_mail.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        pager_account_cash_mail.setOffscreenPageLimit(tabs_fragments_list.size());
    }
```

Additionally my code contains of addTab Function which dynamically adds the tab into the tab layout after service response and after the tabs are added I make call to these two functions.

Whenever setAdapter line executes the debugger went into the getItem function of viewpager adapter and as soon as all the items are returns the app crashes saying :

> Process: com.foo.myapplication, PID: 17278
>                                                                                      java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions
>                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1626)
>                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:679)
>                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:166)
>                                                                                          at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1240)
>                                                                                          at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1088)
>                                                                                          at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1614)
>                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17356)
>                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5367)
>                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1467)
>                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
>                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:638)
>                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17356)
>                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5367)
>                                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17356)
>                                                                                          at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
>                                                                                          at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
>                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17356)
>                                                                                          at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1085)
>                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17356)
>                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5367)
>                                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
>                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17356)
>                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5367)
>                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1467)
>                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
>                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:638)
>                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17356)
>                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5367)
>                                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17356)
>                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5367)
>                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1467)
>                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
>                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:638)
>                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17356)
>                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5367)
>                                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2576)
>                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17356)
>                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2056)
>                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1199)
>                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1405)
>                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1087)
>                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6040)
>                                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:793)
>                                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:606)
>                                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:575)
>                                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:779)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5538)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30293192/fragment-already-added-illegalstateexception-in-viewpager check this